# How to remove unnecessary space from a string using regular expression and trim in java

Tags: java, regex, string

My requirement is remove all unnecessary spaces from a string with using regular expression.

I have a string like this:

```
"name=john    age=26     year=1999";
```

I want to  remove Unnecessary space between two eliminator, expecting output

```
"name=john age=26 year=1999;"
```

Comment: i dont think its a good idea trieing to achieve this with regular expressions

Comment: @deterministicFail Why not?

Comment: then how to  do can you tell me determinstic

Comment: but  how to do with help of regx can you provide some code snip it

Comment: @user3667783 there are some correct answers below these comments.

Answer (score 4):

```
account = account.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: `" name=john   age=26    year=1999  "` gave me one space at the beginning.

Comment: @tailorBird use trim() after the above code `account = account.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#replaceAll` and use reg-ex `"[ \t]+"` to replace multiple space with a single one like this:

```
 account.replaceAll("[ \t]+", " ");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will "fail" on tabs and similar whitespace.

Comment: Why the class (`[]`)?

Comment: I agree with you. but OP only asked for multiple spaces. that's why i just used `[ ]` instead `\\s`. Adding \t to it :)

Comment: @Sanjeev `x+` is the same as `[x]+`, even if `x` is a space.

Comment: @Biffen agreed just correcting it. Thanks

Comment: `[ \t]` still leaves out a lot of spaces.

Comment: @Biffen again agree, i can replace it with \\s but then it will be same as other answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
    String before ="    name=john   age=26     year=1999  ";  
    String  after = before.replaceAll("\t", " ");
    after = after.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    System.out.println(after);
```

Answer (score -3):

There's a regular expressions for finding space, now just replace it

```
/\s+/
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that isn't proper the Java regex for the task...